# Java puzzle accessing main's arguments without them being passed in

Tags: java

I have a Java puzzle I'm having trouble solving. Given the following three classes:

```
public class A1 {
    protected boolean foo() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
public class B1 extends A1 {
}
```

```
public class C1 {
    private static boolean secret = false;

    public boolean foo() {
        secret = !secret;
        return secret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C1 c = new C1();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            c.foo();
        }
        A1 a = new B1();
        if (a.foo() == c.foo()) {
            System.out.println("success!");
        }
    }
}
```

I need to complete the class B1 , however I want, **without** change the classes `A1` and `C1` or adding new files, such that for **at least one** argument, `C1` will always print the string "success!".

I think that I need to override the method `foo()` of the class `A1`,
and rewrite it by getting the number of arguments from the main function on `C1`, to get the right return value.

My problem is that I don't know how to do that. (Remember that I'm not allowed to solve this problem by writing `A1 a = new B1(args.length)` instead of `A1 a = new B1()`. That'd be too easy.)

Any suggestions on how to do it, or even totally different solutions, would be appreciated!

Comment: Any rules about using reflection?

Comment: you can do whatever you like, as long you complete only class B1 without changing the classes A1,C1 and not adding additional files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `secret` is static, you could just create a new `C1` and call `foo` on that, just be sure to invert the result as well:

```
class B1 extends A1 {

    public boolean foo() {
        return !(new C1().foo());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution!,  Just for knowledge, do you think there is a solution for my problem as I have shown above?

Comment: @MrSonic For the problem of accessing the `args` array from B1, not that I know of. Although I suppose technically a VM implementation could choose to capture the arguments in some globally accessible place, e.g. the system properties. Either way, I suspect this is the expected solution to the puzzle :)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe I didn't understand question but I think

```
protected boolean foo() {
    return false;
}
```

In class B1 will be working

Comment: guess nope... number of arguments could be different